# sending email in kohana

Tags: php, email, kohana, kohana-3

hi friends how to send a email through kohana 3.0

i tried but not working 
my code is like this

```
 $subject = ' : Message to Leet Street';
 $from = array('Clarence', 'ratnaraju.java@gmail.com');
 email::send('ratnaraju.bonam@gmail.com', $from , $subject, 'hi how r u Brother ');
 url::redirect();
```

config file is:

```
return array
(
'default' => array(
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'options' => array
        (
        'hostname' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'ratnaraju.bonam@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'Ratna',
        'port' => '465',
    ),
)
```

);

thanks in advance

Comment: ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'email' not found

Comment: Have you tried enabling the *email* module in the bootstrap.php?

Comment: Is there any module, named "email" in modules catalog?

Answer (score 6):

Use this module to send email:
https://github.com/shadowhand/email
it needs this vendor in the vendor-dir:
https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer

Comment: if the class was not found you can't send emails, ofcourse. So you need an email module to do it for you, or write your own function, but then you should use a class. Use the one linked above. It's really good.